# How to get a value in a callback function out of the callback

Tags: javascript, webpack, callback, webpack-2, urlloader

I am writing a Webpack loader for Pug files.  It loads all the dependent images referenced in the Pug file, uses `file-loader` to copy them to the appropriate directory, and replaces `require()` calls in the Pug file with the URLs of the resultant file.

I am trying to add functionality to allow for data URLs to be interpolated into the Pug file in lieu of file URLs.  I am using `this.loadModule()` to execute `file-loader` now.

This function takes a callback as an argument.  One of the args passed to this callback contains the result of `url-loader`, the data URL.  So, I need this to write into the Pug file that should be output.

The problem is, the entire loader finishes running before that callback ever runs.  So, anything I do with the data in there doesn't end up in the final file.  The overall structure of my program looks like this:

```
module.exports = function pugDepLoader(inputFile) {

/* Setting up various constants and variables. */

/* A while() loop that continually tests inputFile with a 
regex to find require() statements.  

It creates a copy of inputFile called outputFile, 
which it iterates over again and again, 
replacing require() statements with file paths 
one at a time.  

The call to this.loadModule() is within this while() loop. */

/* End of while() loop */

/* Return outputFile to Webpack, which is now a 
string with the Pug file, but with the 
require() statements replaced with 
file paths.  

This is meant to be fed to file-loader to 
get written out to disc. */

}
```

That return statement at the end will get called repeatedly before `this.loadModule()`'s callback ever runs once, as I have discovered with debugging statements.  I need to be able to get that data URL that is provided within the callback into `outputFile` before I return it, so that it will end up in the file that is ultimately written to disc.

Entire source code follows:

```
module.exports = function pugDepLoader(inputFile) {

  const fs = require('fs');
  const path = require('path');
  const loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');

  var options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this);

  //This option is required. It specifies
  //the path to the root of the Pug file's
  //dependencies relative to the location
  //of the Pug files.
  var contextualRoot;

  if(!options || !options.hasOwnProperty('contextualRoot')) {
    throw new Error('You must specify a contextual root');
  }

  else {
    contextualRoot = options.contextualRoot;

    //Ensure there is a trailing slash.
    if(contextualRoot[contextualRoot.length-1] !== '/') {
      contextualRoot = contextualRoot + '/';
    }
  }

  //Determines whether paths should begin with
  //a leading slash. Useful for Express.js
  //compatibility.
  if(!options.hasOwnProperty('absolute')) {
    options.absolute = false;
  }

  //Set up regex to search for require() statements
  const reqRE = new RegExp(/require\(/, 'g');

  //outputFile will be returned containing the
  //appropriately processed Pug
  var outputFile = inputFile.slice();

  //We need to execute reqRE once to kick things
  //off, and we need to save it to a variable
  //because we need information from it.
  let regexResult = reqRE.exec(inputFile);

  //regexResult will be null when there
  //are no more matches to be found in
  //the file.
  while(regexResult != null) {

    //pathStartIndex is the beginning of
    //the path to the required file.
    //We add 1 to skip the opening
    //single quote.
    let pathStartIndex = reqRE.lastIndex+1;

    //We require the path to be wrapped in
    //single quotes, so that we can easily
    //be certain about where the require
    //statement ends.
    if(inputFile[reqRE.lastIndex] !== "'") {
      console.log('FATAL ERROR: File path must be wrapped in single quotes!');
      break;
    }

    //inputPath will hold the actual file path itself.
    let inputPath = inputFile.slice(pathStartIndex, inputFile.indexOf("'", pathStartIndex));

    //pathArray is used to split the
    //path so we can easily extract
    //the file name and path
    //separately.
    let pathArray = inputPath.split('/');

    //Just the file name, with extension.
    let fileName = pathArray.pop();

    //outputPath will define what path should be
    //written into the output Pug file.
    //The user may optionally specify a
    //custom output path.
    let outputPath;

    if(options.outputPath) {
      outputPath = options.outputPath;
    }

    else {
      outputPath = pathArray.join('/');
    }

    //Ensure a trailing slash.
    if(outputPath[outputPath.length-1] !== '/') {
      outputPath = (outputPath + '/');
    }

    //reqStart holds the index of the letter
    //"r" in require(), so that we can remove
    //the require() call and replace it
    //with the file path.
    let reqStart = inputFile.indexOf('require', regexResult.index);

    //reqStmt is the require() statement in
    //full. This will be used with replace()
    //to replace the require() call with a
    //file path in the output file.
    let reqStmt = inputFile.slice(reqStart, inputFile.indexOf('"', pathStartIndex));

    //The final file path, with file name.
    //This will be written into the output
    //Pug file in place of the require()
    //calls.
    let filePath = outputPath + fileName;

    if(options.absolute && filePath[0] !== '/') {
      if(filePath[0] === '.' && filePath[1] === '/') {
        filePath = filePath.slice(1);
      }
      else {
        filePath = '/' + filePath;
      }
    }

    else if(!options.absolute && filePath[0] === '/') {
      filePath = filePath.slice(1);
    }

  this.loadModule(contextualRoot + inputPath, (err, res, srcmap, module) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    if(new RegExp(/data:image/).test(res)) {
      filePath = res.slice(res.indexOf('data:image'), res.lastIndexOf('"'));
    }
  });

    //This takes care of require() calls
    //inside of url() CSS functions,
    //such as are used to declare
    //background images inline.

    //If the word "require" is
    //preceeded by a single quote,
    //it is within a url() function,
    //and so we add appropriate closure
    //for that function to the end of
    //the path.
    if(inputFile[reqStart-1] === "'") {
      filePath = filePath + "');";
    }
    //Write the output.
    outputFile = outputFile.replace(reqStmt, filePath);

    //Run the next iteration of the regex search.
    regexResult = reqRE.exec(inputFile);
  }
  //Return output as a string to Webpack.
  return outputFile;
}
```

Comment: Could you include your code? Your descriptions are good, but it's not clear what "this function" refers to, and which operations in your descriptions are synchronous.

Comment: @4castle I added it.

Comment: You cannot expect the function to return the outputFile synchronously when you need the inputFile that is determined asynchronously. Look into promises or just repeat the callback pattern. Once you have an asynchronous dependency, you must continue to use asynchronous patterns to use any derived value.